# Hamming error correction with non-uniform error correction capability

Tags: error-correcting-codes, hamming-code

If I understood correctly, Hamming codes assume the uniform correction among all the bits. This means all the bits have the same weight in terms of correction.

Are there any error correcting codes out there that assume non-uniform error correction probability among the bits? For example, I want a error correcting code that corrects the first bit all the time, but it is fine to correct the second bit 90% of the time.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you want your error-correction code to satisfy? Try explaining with more words.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Suppose I have a 2-bit code (00, 01, 10, 11). I want my error correction code to fix any error on the most significant bit. However, it is fine if the error correction code can not fix the error on the least significant bit all the time. Let's say I want the error correction to fix error on the least significant bit 90% of the times.

Comment: Hamming codes are worst-case codes: they are designed to fix a certain number of errors. You are interested in a different regime, in which errors happen according to a probabilistic model, and you are interested in your average ability to correct errors; this is the setting behind Shannon's theorem.

Comment: Shannon's theorem talks about the correction ability?

Comment: Shannon's theorem talks about transmitting information. I'm referring to this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I have already read this and are somehow familiar with the concept. Is there any algorithm that actually perform what I want? I want to have a novel error correction mechanism to correct each bit with different probability. The application of this error correction is to correct most significant bits with high probability and correct least significant bits with lower probability. The reason is any error on the most significant bit produces a high deviation to the original value while error on the least significant bits produce a small deviation from the original value.

Answer (score 1):

The topic you want is Unequal Error Protection (UEP) codes. There are a number of constructions in this area and a google scholar search yields quite a few hits.

Intuitively, imagine partitioning your code into disjoint point clouds, where cloud centres are chosen by the more important bits, thus intra-centre distance is high, hence those bits are more robust to noise.

Some references:

On linear unequal error protection codes, B Masnick, J Wolf - IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 1967.

Multilevel codes for unequal error protection
AR Calderbank, N Seshadri - IEEE Transactions on Information Theory,  1993.

A more information theoretic perspective is the Borade et al paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2570.pdf) on the arXiV.

Lastly, Prof. Lloyd Welch published a nice paper on "Codes correcting selected error patterns", which I can't seem to find a reference to.